# HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync crushed without exception

Tags: c#, httpclient

I am trying to call an api(POST method) with HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync. However, it stopped at httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync without any exception.

The source code as below:

```
public static async Task<oResult> PostApi(string JSON_sObject, string sEnd_Url) {
        oResult oResult = new oResult();
        var Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSON_sObject);
        var Url = "http://localhost:44340/" + sEnd_Url;

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        try {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(new Uri(Url), Data); // it stopped here 
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var sResponse_content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<oResult>(sResponse_content);
            }
            else
            {
                return oResult;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogFile(ex);
            return oResult;
        }
    }
```

Please advice me if any issue from the source code.

Thank you

Comment: How are you calling this method? Are you awaiting it? Do you have a very long timeout set and the remote server is slow to respond?

Comment: 1) How are you calling this method
`oResult response = await Util.PostApi(body_object, "end_url", Util.GetLang());`
2) Are you awaiting it
yes im using async and await method to call the api with this method 
3) Do you have a very long timeout set and the remote server is slow to respond?
Can consider is fast respond (around 67 ms when i tested in postman)

Comment: Guessing you have a classic message pump deadlock. You probably called this method with something like `PostApi(...).Result`

Answer (score 0):

you should not trying serialize deserialize twice

remove from your code

```
 var Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSON_sObject);
```

and replace

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(new Uri(Url), Data);
```

with this

```
var content = new StringContent(JSON_sObject, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync(sEnd_Url, content);
```

also fix base httpclient  address

```
     var baseUri= @"http://localhost:44340";
    using HttpClient client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri) };
  try {
```